# count and calculate percentage of each column by threshold in Python

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a following dataframe:

```
studentId   sex     history    english    math    biology
    01      male       75         90       85        60
    02     female      85         80       95        70
    03      male       55         60       78        86
    04      male       90         89       76        80
```

I want get a new table showing the percentage of each subject score higher than a threshold of 80 (80 included). For instance, there are two students' scores higher than 80 on history, thus the percentage of history is 2/4 = 50%.
Does someone can help me to do so with Python? Thanks.

```
history        50%
english        75% 
math           50%
biology        50%
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
s = df.iloc[:, 2:].ge(80).mean().mul(100)
print (s)
history    50.0
english    75.0
math       50.0
biology    50.0
dtype: float64
```

**Explanation**:

First select only necessary columns by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:, 2:])
   history  english  math  biology
0       75       90    85       60
1       85       80    95       70
2       55       60    78       86
3       90       89    76       80
```

Then compare by [`DataFrame.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) (`>=`):

```
print (df.iloc[:, 2:].ge(80))
   history  english   math  biology
0    False     True   True    False
1     True     True   True    False
2    False    False  False     True
3     True     True  False     True
```

And get `mean` with multiple by `100` by [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:, 2:].ge(80).mean().mul(100))
history    50.0
english    75.0
math       50.0
biology    50.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, how can you so quickly transfer my first data table to a Pandas DataFrame as df and print(df)? :)

Comment: I think [`read_clipboard`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html) is really helpfull ;)

Comment: Got it and sincere thanks. Pandas is really great and powerful tool on data mining.

Comment: @ahbon - Absolutely agree.

Comment: btw, I slightly changed your method to make the columns more flexible: cols = ['history', 'english', 'math', 'biology']
df.loc[:, cols].ge(80).mean().mul(100)

Comment: Yes, or `df[cols].ge(80).mean().mul(100)`